# SqlAlchemy Classes Declaration of two dependent classes

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a problem in the file where I declare all my classes mappers.

```
    class Application(AbstractId):

        .........

        key_event_id = ORM.column_property(
                 SA.select([ApplicationEvent.id],
                    correlate = True,
                    from_obj = [Application.__table__.join(ApplicationEvent.__table__)]
                ).as_scalar().label("tag").where(ApplicationEvent.key_event == 1)
            )
            SA.select([ApplicationEvent]).filter(
                        ApplicationEvent.key_event)


    class ApplicationEvent(AbstractId):
        __tablename__ = 'applications_events'

        application_id = SA.Column(SA.Integer, SA.ForeignKey(Application.id), primary_key = True)
        application = ORM.relationship(Application, backref = 'events')
        event_id = SA.Column(SA.Integer, SA.ForeignKey(Event.id), primary_key = True)
        event = ORM.relationship(Event)
```

This won't work since ApplicationEvent is declared before Application. How can I make this work ? I need key_event_id as a column of Application.

This won't work either:

```
@declarative.declared_attr
        def key_event_id(cls):  
            return ORM.column_property(
                 SA.select(['ApplicationEvent.id'],
                    correlate = True,
                    from_obj = ['Application.__table__'.join('ApplicationEvent.__table__')]
                ).as_scalar().where('ApplicationEvent.key_event' == 1).label("key_event_id")
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

[You can simply pass the model name as a string to the `relationship()` call.](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.argument)

> **argument**
>
> a mapped class, or actual Mapper instance, representing the target of
>   the relationship.
>
> argument may also be passed as a callable function which is evaluated
>   at mapper initialization time, and may be passed as a Python-evaluable
>   string when using Declarative.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 application = ORM.relationship("Application", backref = 'events')
```

and

```
 event = ORM.relationship("Event" , order_by="Event.id")
```

You can write like this way

```
application_id = SA.Column("id", SA.ForeignKey("Application.id"), primary_key = True)
application = ORM.relationship("Application", backref = 'events')
event_id = SA.Column("id", SA.ForeignKey("Event.id"), primary_key = True)
event = ORM.relationship("Event")
```

Comment: What about SA.ForeignKey(Application.id) ?

Comment: I already have those relationships declared in my model, but I need that column property, but the interpreter will fail since Application and ApplicationEvent are not yet declared at the time. Setting the models as strings won't work either ( I just update my answer)